# Unable to ping clients present on the same subnet

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking

I have two wireless home routers R1 and R2 on same subnet connected LAN-LAN in the following config (see image in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkxnc.png):

- R1 is connected to internet via its WAN port (not shown in image).
- R2 is connected to R1 via one of its LAN ports
- R1 config: static 192.168.1.1/24  **DHCP server enabled** and used as an **access point 1**
- R2 config: static 192.168.1.2/24  **DHCP server disabled** and used as an **access point 2**
- DHCP server dynamic @ pool: .3 to .50
- Access point 1 have different name and password from access point 2

In simulation everything work fine but when i networked them at home i found that R1 and R2 Clients can access internet normally but they showed the following issues:

- R2 Clients cannot see R1 clients and vice versa (ping failed)
- R2 Clients cannot detect a shared printer present on R1 although they are on the same subnet
- R1 Clients cannot detect a shared printer present on R2 although they are on the same subnet
- R1 Clients cannot connect to R2 admin page

**Your help will be really appreciated.**

Thanks.

Comment: Retrace your connection steps and make sure your 2 points above (LAN to LAN; DHCP on main router, not on the other router) have been properly set up.  Turn both routers off for 2 minutes, turn devices off. Start up the first router, then the second, wait 2 minutes, and turn on the devices.

Comment: When you say "R1 Clients", do you mean *wireless* clients? If so, it's because you have client isolation on.

Comment: @John just checked that, still same problems

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, all clients are wireless clients, how i remove client isolation ?

Comment: @DavidSchwarts i found how to deactivate it and now everyone see each other on the subnet ! I was struggling with the problem for days, thanks man !

Comment: Make sure wireless clients are set to Private and not Public.  You can also delete wireless profiles   (NETSH WLAN and the delete paramater), and then restart and set up the profiles again

Comment: @John it was AP clients isolation problem as mentioned by DavidSchwarts above, problem solved, thanks guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are wireless clients, you need to turn off client isolation.